# Store a number and increase by one with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to store Code and increment by one with a new form submission (payment form with Authorize.Net). However I am getting back some strange numbers. For instance, there is one point it goes from 66 to 55 to 73!

> NULL, NULL, 84, 83, 83, 82, 82, NULL, 81, 80, NULL, 80, 80, NULL,
>   NULL... 75, 74, 73, 55, 66, 72, NULL, 71, 71, 70...

I am thinking my Stored Procedure needs changed, but I am looking for some advice because I do not understand why this is even happening.

Comment: Why not use an identity instead of trying to roll your own? The technique you are is a common one but is incredibly complicated to get correct due to things like concurrency. Just use an identity and this is non-issue.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes I think that is a good idea. Maybe I will switch to this instead.

Answer (score 3):

You should let the database manage the identity column because it is more capable of getting that right than you application(s). Simply add a new IDENTITY column to your Payment table. This will also allow you to easily identify multiple payments against one invoice.

```
ALTER TABLE Payment ADD PaymentID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

//This does not change
INSERT INTO Payment (EventCode, EventInstance, EventCount, InvoiceNumber)

//MAX Payment for invoice 
SELECT PaymentID=MAX(PaymentID)  FROM Payment 
  WHERE (EventCode = @EventCode AND
        EventInstance = @EventInstance)

//OR Since you just inserted on the same connection simply use @IDENTITY
SELECT PaymentID=@IDENTITY
```